# Ocaml: Equivalence of two lists

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

New to Ocaml and have been working on a problem I haven't seen answered yet.
I'm working on a function where there is a tuple of 2 lists that are checked for equivalence.
Example:

```
# equivalence ([1;2],[1;2]);;
- : bool = true
# equivalence ([1;2],[2;1]);;
- : bool = true
# equivalence ([1;2],[1]);;
- : bool = false
```

Code I have:

```
let rec equivalent(a,b) = match a, b with
| [], [] -> true
| [], _
| _, [] -> false
| c::cc, d::dd -> if c = d then equivalent(cc,dd) else false;;
```

I know the problem lies with the last line. I can get a result of true if all elements are in the same order, but out of order it is a result of false. I'm having trouble going through one list to see if the other list has the element. I've tried to use List.nth, .hd, and .tl (not allowed to use .map or .itr) and have also tried to avoid the imperative features of Ocaml. Any suggestions or somewhere I should look? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are your requirements? Two lists are usually not considered to be equivalent when they have different order (an important property of lists). Do you want to treat them as sets? Do you want to treat them as multisets?

Comment: Generally the requirements are to not use any imperative features like nested let functions, using let to declare variables, and generally all the imperative features listed in the Ocaml manual.

Comment: And I have no real experience with sets in Ocaml. Lists are wanted, but I guess I am having trouble treating them like a set would want to be treated. Basically, not sure how to tell how each list has the same values without them being in the same order. Not asking for an answer but somewhere to look would help.

Comment: Either test whether each value of one list is contained in the other list (and reverse), or sort both lists and then test them for (list) equivalence.

Comment: I've tried to do those both, but I'm having trouble with getting the exact syntax right. For example, I've tried for the last line to do `else (a,dd);;` instead of `else false;;` Just not sure what tool to use and how to get the syntax down. I know the example in this comment doesn't fix it exactly, but I guess that's part of where my confusion is. If it helps, the signature should be `'a list * 'a list -> bool`

Comment: You say you're trying to sort a list. It looks like this: `let sorted_list = List.sort compare unsorted_list in ...` If you sort the lists first then checking for equality will be much easier. (In fact your existing code looks really close already.)

Comment: Are you sure about ```# equivalence ([1;2],[2;1])``` returning ```true```. It returns false when I run it.

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you are trying to accomplish.  I agree with @BikalLem that the first listing doesn't seem to be what would be generated by the second.  Does that listing show what you *want*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is some homework where you have to treat lists as poor mans set.

As Bergi mentioned performance wise the best would be to first sort both list and then compare them with your existing code. But that is probably not how you are supposed to solve this.

Assuming the lists are mend to be sets with not duplicate entries then equivalence of a and b means that a contains every element of b and b contains every element of a.

Start by writing a function `contains: 'a -> 'a list -> bool` that checks if an item is in a list. Next a function `contains_all: 'a list -> 'a list -> bool` that uses contains to check if every item in the first list is in the second. That then gives you

```
let equivalence a b = (contains_all a b) && (contains_all b a)
```

If your lists can contains duplicates then go with sorting the lists first. Anything else is just too impractical.

Note: `contains` exists as `List.mem` if you are allowed to use that.